# How to recover the data removed by "rm"?

Tags: linux, centos, disk, rm, data-recovery

I falsely deleted some very important data by using the "rm" command on CentOS 7.0.  But after that, I haven't done any more operations on that effected disk. Is there any way to recover those data?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming or just too broad.

Comment: The other thing worth mentioning: the more time elapses between your lapse of running "rm" accidentally  and you taking "counter actions" ... the smaller your chances go to regain lost data. Thus the first impulse should be to use your favorite search engine extensively; instead putting time into writing down questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The real question is how many more times you will have to read this:

> "**We also recommend to have always a Backup for your Important files**"

before you take it seriously.

---

My feeling is that your data are gone. However, your best bet would be to make an image of whatever you have right now and then see if there is anything left to be found using whatever tools you wish.

Read more in [undo rm- R in centOS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91297/how-to-undelete-just-deleted-directory-with-rm-r-command).